# Making border on html in a particular column

Tags: html

how to add a border only on the fields I expected as the example below,

```html
<table width="500" border="1">
    <tr>
  <td>no border</td>
  <td>no border</td>
  <td>Just</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>no border</td>
  <td>no border</td>
  <td>Border</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td>no border</td>
  <td>no border</td>
  <td>here 1 box</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a class to those specific `td` that you want. I also removed the `border=1` from `<table border="1">`

HTML:

```
<table width="200">
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="modified-td-top">Just</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="modified-td-middle">Border</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="modified-td-bottom">here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {border:0px;border-collapse: collapse;}

.modified-td-middle {
border-left:1px solid black;
border-right:1px solid black;
}

.modified-td-top {
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.modified-td-bottom {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-right: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: thanks @gosi123 less precise, I want to make the border only to column 3 without the middle line as merger

Answer (score 0):

is this what u meant ?

**EDIT**

```html
<table width="200" style="border:1px solid black;">
    <tr style="border:none">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Just</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border:none">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>Border</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border:none">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: slightly less, so in the 3 column it into one box

Comment: not, so the line in the middle is missing, as in merger

Comment: but not all tables, but only columns to 3 are no words "just border here"

Comment: @dwiyanto sorry, i dont get you